# Numbering subtables in a single section

Tags: tables, book-class

I am using a book document class and I want to know how to make a table numbering style like 1.1.a., 1.1.b for subtables in the form section.table.subtable, usually in the same section for example? The purpose of making subtables is just to explain each of them individually.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}

\section{Some section}

\noindent First subtable

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{a}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.7in}|} \hline 
 & $\mathrm{\spadesuit}$ & $\mathrm{\varheartsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\vardiamondsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\clubsuit}$ \\
\hline
1. & A  & K & 9  & K \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent Another subtable

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{b}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.7in}|} \hline 
 & $\mathrm{\spadesuit}$ & $\mathrm{\varheartsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\vardiamondsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\clubsuit}$ \\
\hline
2. & A & B & C & D \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: What does "1.1.a" in "Table 1.1.a" correspond to? Is it `section.subsection.table` or `section.table.subtable` or something entirely different? Please clarify.

Comment: Since you state "The purpose of making subtables is just to explain each of them individually.": As long as each table has an individual caption, you can also explain them individually/ refer to them. I don't really see the connection to subtable numbering here.

Comment: @leandriis this should be section.table.subtable

Comment: Would something like the following be acceptable for you? A shared caption for both tables with individual subcaptions for each of them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tns34.png

Comment: This is slightly acceptable. But lets say I want to describe immediately subtable that follows a paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two versions without a shared caption:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}

\usepackage{subcaption,array}


\DeclareCaptionSubType*[alph]{table}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mystyle}{Table~\bothIfFirst{#1}{ }#2}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}

\section{Some section}


\begin{table}[htbp]

  \begin{subtable}{0.475\linewidth}
     \centering
    \caption{subcaption} \label{subtab:left}
    \begin{tabular}{|wl{0.1in}|wl{0.3in}|wl{0.3in}|wl{0.3in}|wl{0.3in}|} 
      \hline 
      & $\mathrm{\spadesuit}$ & $\mathrm{\varheartsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\vardiamondsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\clubsuit}$ \\
      \hline
      1. & A  & K & 9  & K \\
      \hline 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}\hfill
  \begin{subtable}{0.475\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{subcaption} \label{subtab:right}
    \begin{tabular}{|wl{0.1in}|wl{0.3in}|wl{0.3in}|wl{0.3in}|wl{0.3in}|} 
      \hline 
      & $\mathrm{\spadesuit}$ & $\mathrm{\varheartsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\vardiamondsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\clubsuit}$ \\
      \hline
      1. & A  & K & 9  & K \\
      \hline 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}


Reference to first subtable: \ref{subtab:left}

Reference to second subtable: \ref{subtab:right}

\newpage


First subtable

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{caption text} \label{subtab:upper}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.7in}|} \hline 
 & $\mathrm{\spadesuit}$ & $\mathrm{\varheartsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\vardiamondsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\clubsuit}$ \\
\hline
1. & A  & K & 9  & K \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

Another subtable

\begin{table}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{caption text}  \label{subtab:lower}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.7in}|} \hline 
 & $\mathrm{\spadesuit}$ & $\mathrm{\varheartsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\vardiamondsuit}$ & $\mathrm{\clubsuit}$ \\
\hline
2. & A & B & C & D \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}



Reference to first subtable: \ref{subtab:upper}

Reference to second subtable: \ref{subtab:lower}

\end{document}
```